# Using headers as condition with VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I need some help with the following VBA code:

```
Sub Myfiltermacro()

Range("[summary_table[All#]").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CriteriaRange:=Range("condition[All#]"), CopyToRange:=Range("C14:S14"), Unique:=False

End Sub
```

This is a copied code from the following site (https://www.goodly.co.in/automated-filter-with-macro/), I don´t know VBA but I found one code that would suit my need but I cannot make it to work.

The idea is to filter using headers as a condition, but I have the following error: `VBA error: 1004 method 'range' for object global failed`

I have my main table formatted as a table and also the headers that I want to be able to filter.

I don't know if I need to have more information here, let me know.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You appear to have an extraneous opening bracket when referring to `summary_table`.

It should be:

```
Range("summary_table[All#]") not Range("[summary_table[All#]")
```